# Left align text on bulletpoints inline

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to left align the text on my bulletpoints (because it somehow appears centered) with this:

```
    <div style="width: 100%;margin:0 auto;text-align:left">
<ul>
 <li>Rechtsanwalt seit 2000</li>
 <li>Fachanwalt für Arbeitsrecht</li>
 <li>Fachanwalt für Steuerrecht</li>
 <li>Abogado spanischen Rechts seit 2001</li>
 <li>Zertifizierter Testamentsvollstrecker (AGT)</li>
 <li>Fachberater für Unternehmensnachfolge</li>
</ul> </div> <br><br>
```

You see the result here: http://staging.robering-fries.de/team-member/christof-fries
It is obviously not working...
Where do I go wrong?

Thanks
Florian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 'li's is the elements that have `text-align: center;` on them. From your website:

```
.attorney-team-details li {
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    border-radius: 100%;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-align: center; // <==
}
```

so you can change this property in your `shortcodes.css` file, or adding `text-align: left;` to each `li`.

Comment: Ah, this method is more elegant than mine.

Comment: This is exactly right, thank you! As I don't have a childtheme and want my changes to stick (even when updating), I will add "text-align: left" to every li.

Comment: @FlorianT. If this solution solve your problem, please mark as the correct answer.

Comment: Yes I did! Stackoverflow wont let you do that to quickly ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Please add `text-align:left` to `li` element.

```
<div style="width: 100%;margin:0 auto;">
<ul>
 <li style="text-align:left">Rechtsanwalt seit 2000</li>
 <li style="text-align:left">Fachanwalt für Arbeitsrecht</li>
 <li style="text-align:left">Fachanwalt für Steuerrecht</li>
 <li style="text-align:left">Abogado spanischen Rechts seit 2001</li>
 <li style="text-align:left">Zertifizierter Testamentsvollstrecker (AGT)</li>
 <li style="text-align:left">Fachberater für Unternehmensnachfolge</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Or you can use css class and `!important`:

```
div.myAlign ul li{
    text-align:left!important;
}

<div class="myAlign" style="width: 100%;margin:0 auto;">
<ul>
 <li style="text-align:left">Rechtsanwalt seit 2000</li>
 <li style="text-align:left">Fachanwalt für Arbeitsrecht</li>
 <li style="text-align:left">Fachanwalt für Steuerrecht</li>
 <li style="text-align:left">Abogado spanischen Rechts seit 2001</li>
 <li style="text-align:left">Zertifizierter Testamentsvollstrecker (AGT)</li>
 <li style="text-align:left">Fachberater für Unternehmensnachfolge</li>
</ul>
</div>
```